# How to understand the trade-off between looping and extra numpy dimensions when doing matrix work?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

A common pattern I find myself in is the following:

```
matrix_list1 = [...]  # list of N ndarrays of shape (100,100)
matrix_list2 = [...]  # list of N ndarrays of shape (100, 100)
result = []
for i in range(N):
    M = matrix_list1[i] * matrix_list2[i]
    result.append(M)
```

Alternatively, we can do this without a loop by stacking the matrices in the two lists:

```
M1 = np.stack(matrix_list1)
M2 = np.stack(matrix_list2)
result = M1*M2
```

Is the second method always faster, assuming we can hold those stacks in memory? Is it merely a speed vs memory trade-off? How can I better understand this?

Comment: Use `%timeit` in `ipython` to run benchmarks.

Comment: You might also want to include a `np.stack(result)` in the timing loop, if you want an array in both cases.  My general rule of thumb is that a modest number of iterations on a complex calculation can be faster if memory use gets large.  Many iterations on smaller calculations are always slower. But there's no hard-and-fast tradeoff.

Comment: @hpaulj. At which point it often becomes a question of whether you can generate the data directly into an array or to have to convert. Once that overhead leaves the picture it's not much of a contest

Answer (score 0):

`M1` and `M2` are each a single (small) metadata object and a contiguous block of memory. They each take up less space than the original `matrix_list1` and `matrix_list2`. The latter require storage for multiple sets of metadata and the list structure itself. There is no sacrifice of size when switching to a single array.

The vectorized multiply operation might be marginally faster across a contiguous block than a number of separate segments as well, even discounting the overhead of looping. This is especially true if the blocks are not a multiple of the size loaded into the processor cache.

When performing a pipeline of sufficiently complex operations, it sometimes turns out faster to run a python-level loop in order to eliminate some expensive operations. This is especially true if the number of iterations is very small. In your case, there is only one operation that is competing with the loop: conversion to an array. For a small number of matrices, the loop *might* be marginally faster.

If you remove the array conversion entirely, you can make the whole operation much faster by using vectorization across a contiguous buffer. Specifically, if you can load the matrices into a 3D array to begin with instead of using lists, eliminating the loop will be the optimal solution. Until you figure out how to do that, benchmarking the two options is the only way to know for sure which is faster.